What does, "there is no truth in him" mean in John 8:44?
John 8:44 ESV

"You are of your father the devil, and your will is to do your father's desires. He was a murderer from the beginning, and has nothing to do with  the truth, because there is no truth in him. When he lies, he speaks out of his own character, for he is a liar and the father of lies." [My emphasis].

"truth" here is aletheia.
James 2:19

"You believe that God is one; you do well. Even the demons believe- and shudder."

How can there be no truth in him, the devil, when demons believe that God is one? Is that not a truth that being in them is also in him?

The most dangerous "perfect lie" consists mostly of truth. Demons believe - and shudder, while true believers believe - and love, because there is no fear in love — 1 John 4:18. Demons know God exist, but the fear of the LORD is the beginning of knowledge — Proverbs 1:7; they have no love, only knowledge, but the truth is love, because God is love — 1 John 4:16.

Can you say what contradiction you see there?
To me, for one, whether there can be truth in him, the devil is one thing; whether demons believe that God is one, quite another.
How d'you think such separate things, let alone anyone's beliefs about them, can be compared?
Further, what could 'Is that not a truth that being in them is also in him?' change?

@Robbie Goodwin You use the word "contradiction". I did not use this word. I asked "How" i.e., how do these things fit together? "How" implies there is no contradiction but that they do fit.

So sorry, C.Stroud; did you think I wasn't entitled to speak about 'contradiction' because you hadn't used that word? Really?
'How' doesn't at all imply there is no contradiction, or that they do fit…
Could you think back and try again?

@Robbie Goodwin I think asking how a car engine works  implies that it does work. And Mary in Luke 1:34 shows, I think, no lack of faith in asking "how will this be?" My question did not seek to imply contradiction but to clarify in what ways devil/demons know truths but not in the sense of "the truth will set you free" John 8:32.

Could you drop your own interpretations of what implies anything, and try genuine logic? For instance, do you not see the difference between 'How' actually implying anything, and merely assuming? Could you focus on the point?

The point is, in my view far too simply for an Answer here, that it would be hard indeed to defend the idea, your citation of John 8:44 ESV could mean anything but 'His an out and out liar; there is no truth in him whatsoever.'
Can you say how it helps, here, to define the single word 'truth' as 'aletheia'?
How could James 2:19 change anything in your John?
Is English not your first language?

@Robbie Goodwin To see significance of "alethia" compare "alethes" God is true [cannot lie] John 3:33 and Romans 3:4 with "alethino" the living and true God [as opposed to false god] 1 Thessalonians 1:9 and John 17:3.

Thanks and why not Edit that into the Question? Either way, is the real Question now revealed to be the rather different 'How can there be "no truth" anywhere, if God is one?'

Beside anything else, do you recognise the expression 'I have more (whatever) in my little finger than he has in his whole body'?

Either way, doesn't the opposite, 'I have less (whatever) in my little finger than he has in his whole body' work for you?

How could 'He has less truth in his whole body than I have in the smallest joint of my little finger…' not work for you?

@Robbie Goodwin I acknowledge reading your comments but at the moment fail to see how they add clarity to this question.

@C.Stroud Again how could 'He has less truth in his whole body than I have in the smallest joint of my little finger…' not work for you?

@Robbie Goodwin If the devil knows that God is one because that is what the devil believes, then in what sense is the truth not in the devil? [There is no truth in him].

The choice is yours and would you rather have a serious discussion, or play childish games?

@Robbie Goodwin Comments are for clarification not discussion.  I will not be commenting to you for discussion.

Still your choice and p'rap it would help if you looked at the other end. Remember anyone telling you 'I have more (blah) in my little finger than he has in his entire body?
Well, 'there is no truth in him' is pretty much the same.
Why not trust all the Answers and other people's Comments here?

A lie is the opposite of the truth, told with full knowledge of the reality. So there is no contradiction in John stating that Satan has no truth in him. Although Satan knows that God loves humanity, he continually attempts to prove to God that humans are evil and undeserving of His love. To do this, Satan employs various cunning strategies to provoke human evil. Key tactics include:

Deception - Involves twisting the truth or presenting attractive alternatives, as seen when he asked Eve, "Did God really say?" (Genesis 3:1)
Temptation - By appealing to human desires such as greed, lust, pride, as he did when telling Eve that God forbade them from eating the fruit because they would be like God (Genesis 3:3)
Accusation - He provokes feelings of guilt and shame in individuals, making them feel unworthy of forgiveness and driving them further from God. Satan attempted this with Job but he failed, as Job maintained his faithfulness to God.
Division - By sowing discord and conflict, Satan creates divisions among people - whether in families, communities, or nations - leading to strife and animosity.
Distraction - By keeping people busy on worldly concerns, he prevents them from seeking spiritual growth and maintaining a relationship with God.

John claims there is no truth in Satan because, although Satan knows what the truth is, he chooses to act in opposition to it.

I think you have over complicated the words of "there is no truth in him", the devil is the wholly deceitful and untruthful.

for he is a liar and the father of lies

Also there is seemly an issue with your ESV translation as one sentence and has nothing to do with the truth should be "and does not stand in the truth" I think this is important because it adds a sort of contextual support for the sentence you are talking about.
this support being that the devil from the beginning has never stood in the truth and has opposed God in his heart ever since, he deceived eve, he deceived many many angels to rebel against God, and he is constantly deceiving humans to rebel against God and worship him as the mighty, which he wanted.

Christ is pointing out a contrast between God and the Devil, as the people whom he is speaking to called their father Abraham and of God and Christ responded John 8:42-43 ESV

42 Jesus said to them, “If God were your Father, you would love me, for I came from God and I am here. I came not of my own accord, but he sent me. 43 Why do you not understand what I say? It is because you cannot bear to hear my word.

Christ is taking about how none of these people will accept the truth and that they are evil and deceitful, their spiritual father is not of God but of the devil who is wholly untruthful and dishonest in contrast to God who is wholly truthful and honest.

Satan and his angels know God is the creator, they have known this since they were created, the Devil wanted to be like God or aka be God, this was the Satans pride, his pride caused him to fall.
Isaiah 14:12-14 ESV

“How you are fallen from heaven,
O Day Star, son of Dawn!
How you are cut down to the ground,
you who laid the nations low!
You said in your heart,
‘I will ascend to heaven;
above the stars of God
I will set my throne on high;
I will sit on the mount of assembly
in the far reaches of the north;
I will ascend above the heights of the clouds;
I will make myself like the Most High.’


"there is seemly an issue with your ESV translation" is a rather audacious claim.  There are many differences among the wordings of various translations.  That does not inherently make any of them wrong.  Nor does how literal the translation is.  You may prefer different wording, but you have not presented any reason why anyone else should do.

Just to be clear, while the ESV sucks, in this particular instance it is just copying wording from the RSV without alteration. The RSV was merging the KJV's "abode not in the truth" with the RV and ASV's "stood/standeth not in the truth" and decided for a novel retranslation of the source, "καὶ ἐν τῇ ἀληθείᾳ οὐκ ἔστηκεν", to try to communicate the point better. That this can be regarded as a translation mistake, we could point out that e.g. the NRSV reverts back to "does not stand in" as its translation of "οὐκ ἔστηκεν" (the latter term does literally connote still or  standing).

Simple AnswerAs modern translations clarify, the first scripture deals with the Spirit world's conduct. (John 8:44) His nefarious actions are renown for being based on lies. And then their "ugly sisters": deception, impunning character, trivial distractions, lustful temptation, false accusations, accompany them.
The second verse deals with belief systems. Yes, even demons (devils) know  what reality is all about. (James 2:19) In the book of Job, Satan came and stood in the Presence of God. (Job 1:6) And Satan (Devil) stood toe-to-toe, face-to-face against Jesus in the Judean Wilderness. He knows Whom he is up against!
There is no contradiction in these two verses. Just warnings for every skeptic who attacks Jesus---and, as well, for every believer to be alert!

Put on the whole armor of God so you may be able to stand against the wiles of the Devil.  For we don't wrestle against flesh and blood, but against principalities, against powers, against the rulers of darkness of this world, against spiritual wickedness` in high places. (Ephesians 6:11-12)


I think you've hit on the crux of the matter here. "there is no truth in him", or alternative translations of the same original text, doesn't mean that the Enemy and his minions don't know the truth. Rather, it is about their fundamentally deceptive and untruthful behavior.  Even if one were otherwise uncertain about that, the James verse speaks to that question.
